# Convertir consulta a LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Tengo los datos en un `DataTable` en lugar de tenerlos en base de datos. Quiero obtener los mismos resultados mediante LINQ hacia un `DataTable`. Necesito pasar a LINQ esta consulta:

```
SELECT proveedor, COUNT(*) AS cantidad, SUM(importe) AS SumaImporte 
FROM prueba 
GOUP BY PERIODO, MENSUALIDAD, TIPO, PROVEEDOR;
```

He probado con esto, pero no consigo formarlo correctamente:

```
var groupedData = from b in prueba.AsEnumerable() group new b.Field("PERIODO") by b into g select new { ChargeTag = g.Key, Count = g.Count(), ChargeSum = g.Sum(x => x.Field("IMPORTE")) }; //error de compilacion

foreach (var line in prueba.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(info => info["IMPORTE"]) .Select(group => new { Metric = group.Key, Count = group.Count() }) ///No funciona
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria una cosa así...

```
var result = Prueba
        .GroupBy(p => p.Periodo,p.Mensualidad,p.Tipo, p.Proveedor)
        .Select(cp => new PruebaDto
                {
                    Proveedor= cp.First().Proveedor,
                    Cantidad= cp.Count().ToString(),
                    SumaImporte= cp.Sum(c => c.Importe).ToString(),
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Al probar eso me devolvió un solo resultado. Y eran 272 registros, no tengo muy claro que sea correcto.

Comment: No tiene ningún tipo de filtro, te debería de llegar todos los registros. Comprueba que el objeto Prueba estén todos.